# Deploy Azure Data Factory by just providing project file (Not coding Linked services, Datasets separately)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to know how to deploy an ADF from a Visual studio project file in which only the Resources (eg: Azure SQL ) are defined?
I want the linked services to be generated automatically for the specifies resources.